# SQL: I want to get specific rows using rownum on a where conditioned query

Tags: sql

```
"select id from sale_order where write_date > '" + deFromDate.Text + "' and write_date < '" + deToDate.Text + "' order by id desc"
```

I am implementing Paging using Sql. so, want specific rows using starting and ending rownum on this query.

Comment: For now i am implementing like this but getting null in the result list.

"WITH filter_query AS (select id from sale_order where write_date > '" + deFromDate.Text + "' AND write_date < '" + deToDate.Text + "' order by id desc) SELECT * FROM filter_query WHERE ROWNUM >= '" + startRowNum + "' AND ROWNUM <= '" + endRowNum + "' "

Comment: There is no standard syntax for specifying intervals in the result set. You'll need to tell us which database product you are using. Or else return all the rows and handle it in a procedural language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL we can use `LIMIT` for this purpose

```
select id from sale_order where write_date > '" + deFromDate.Text + "' and
 write_date < '" + deToDate.Text + "' order by id desc LIMIT x, y
```

In SQL Server 2005

```
SELECT id 
FROM (
    SELECT id, write_date, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID DESC) AS RowNum
    FROM sale_order 
     ) AS MyDerivedTable
WHERE MyDerivedTable.write_date > '" + deFromDate.Text + "' and
MyDerivedTable.write_date < '" + deToDate.Text + "' MyDerivedTable.RowNum 
BETWEEN @startRow AND @endRow
```

Comment: I am using PushGrace Sql and done this work using limit and offset. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Answer can be change with sql server that you are using. Following query works in sql server 2008 R2.

```
DECLARE @offset AS INT, @limit AS INT
SET @offset = 11
SET @limit = 10    
SELECT id 
FROM (
       SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS row_num
       FROM sale_order
       WHERE write_date > '" + deFromDate.Text + "' and write_date < '" + deToDate.Text + "' 
     ) AS sale_order
WHERE sale_order.row_num BETWEEN @offset AND (@offset + @limit) ORDER BY id DESC
```